# DSE Graph Loader geospatial data

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

The docs don't provide examples of importing geospatial data (e.g. points) using Graph Loader. Is this possible? For example, I want to load some vertices, each of which has a property `coordinates` of type `Geo.point`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I figured out is that you can use the WKT, so e.g. for a point property, in JSON:

```
// MyVertex.json
{"name": "foobar", "coordinates": "POINT (45, 45)"}
```

With a mapping file like this:

```
load(myVertexInput).asVertices {
    label "MyVertex"
    key "name"
}
```

I think with this example that the `coordinates` property needs to be defined already in the schema.